# Couldn't import the updated zip file using creative exchange import wizard?

Tags: sxa

Issue in creative exchange import functionality

Uploaded packages are not visible in the select package wizard, so we couldn’t select the package to import, but file uploading is successful. It is stored inside the app-data/package/creativeexchange.

It is problem with the DataFolder path which is defined in the sitecore.config file, I have given the relative path. SXA Import select package wizard is looking for the packages inside the C:/App_Data folder, but it stored the uploaded file in the relative path.

Give absolute path in dataFolder value, to resolve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am using SXA v1.6 in Sitecore 9.0.1 and still encountered the problem. The dataFolder fix still resolved the issue.

The dataFolder settings variable is located in your `\App_Config\Sitecore.config`

```
<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xp0.sc\App_Data" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Well, not an issue as I asked this to support and they don't seem to want to fix it.

The reason why is that the installation manual (for 8.2-upd2 in my case) clearly mentioned (somewhere) that you should set the datafolder to an absolute path - so they're covered.

To get to the actual reason why it's not working: in the export code, a MapPath is used to the relative folder works correctly during upload of the package. But on import (and for listing the packages) that MapPath is not there...  and so only absolute datafolder paths work.

Comment: I've fixed this yesterday:)

Answer (score 0):

*This is a known issue. Well, not an issue as I asked this to support and they don't seem to want to fix it.*

I've fixed this yesterday:)

Wait for SXA 1.6 where Creative Exchange will be working with absolute and relative paths for Data folder.

Comment: Finally.. thanks Dawid! One more reason to look forward to 1.6 :)